# How to wrap my macro in a IF EXIST clause

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have the following code:

```
If Sheets("EstimateTemplate").Visible Then
    Sheets("EstimateTemplate").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Sheets("Navigation").Select
Else
    Sheets("EstimateTemplate").Visible = True
    Sheets("Navigation").Select
End If
```

how can I wrap it with "IF SHEET EXISTS" clause

I tried the following which didn't work

```
IF not Sheets("EstimateTemplate") = "" then
   If Sheets("EstimateTemplate").Visible Then
   Sheets("EstimateTemplate").Select
   ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
   Sheets("Navigation").Select
   Else
   Sheets("EstimateTemplate").Visible = True
   Sheets("Navigation").Select
   End If
end if
```

Comment: my bad. forgot i asked that question. fix worked.

Answer (score 0):

[I take a solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040164/excel-vba-if-worksheetwsname-exists) as a good one:

There's no built-in function for this.

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wb As Excel.Workbook)
   Dim s As Excel.Worksheet
   If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   On Error Resume Next
   Set s = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
   On Error GoTo 0
   SheetExists = Not s Is Nothing
End Function
```

So you end up in:

```
IF SheetExists("EstimateTemplate") then
   If Sheets("EstimateTemplate").Visible Then
      Sheets("EstimateTemplate").Select
      ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
      Sheets("Navigation").Select
   Else
      Sheets("EstimateTemplate").Visible = True
      Sheets("Navigation").Select
   End If
End if
```